# st_union error: deprecated C function 'pgis_geometry_union_finalfn'

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have a database on Heroku with Postgis installed. My system relies heavily on geometric operations such as st_union. I guess Heroku updated my postgis version recently and now all my queries that use functions like st_union or st_overlap produce this error:

```
[0A000] ERROR: A stored procedure tried to use deprecated C function 'pgis_geometry_union_finalfn' Detail: Library function 'pgis_geometry_union_finalfn' was deprecated in PostGIS 3.3.0 Hint: Consider running: SELECT postgis_extensions_upgrade()
```

Is this correct? Have these functions been removed? Are there alternative functions?

I am running Postgis version 3.3.2 and Postgres version 14.6

Comment: O'd follow the hint.

Comment: Which PostGIS version you had previously? Have you tried running `SELECT postgis_extensions_upgrade()`?

Comment: yes I have, I get error: "Extension updates are disabled, you may drop the extension and re-create it.". However, I checked the latest Postgis version and it's 3.3.2, which is the version I am running.